# Issues with Grails 3 domain class named "Application"

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a legacy system that I am migrating to Grails 3 but I'm running into a naming convention issue.  One of our tables is called `Application` but that is also the name of the Groovy class that runs the application.  There seems to be an issue where GORM is confusing the 2 classes and giving type-casting errors.  I have tried explicitly casting my `Application` class in my `ApplicationDegree` class to try and force GORM to recognize which class I am trying to use but no success.

I know an option is that I can rename my domain `Application` class to something else and manually map it to the appropriate database table but I want to avoid that as I foresee issues down the road.

So, other than renaming my Domain classes, how can I get Grails/GORM to make the correct mapping.

**Grails 3.1.4**

Code:

```
ApplicationDegree ad = ApplicationDegree.findById(10);
```

Class:

```
class ApplicationDegree {

    Boolean isPrimary
    domain.package.Application application
    Degree degree

    static hasMany = [applicationDegreeMajors: ApplicationDegreeMajor,
                      applicationDegreeMinors: ApplicationDegreeMinor]
    static belongsTo = [domain.package.Application, Degree]

    static mapping = {
        version false
        degree column: 'degree_code'
        isPrimary column: 'isPrimary'
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
ERROR org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Bean couldn't be autowired using grails optimization: Property 'application' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
ERROR org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory - Retrying using spring autowire
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app4grad_V2/college/applications/
Cannot convert value of type [app4grad.Application] to required type [domain.package.Application] for property 'application': no matching editors or conversion strategy found. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate entity:  : domain.package.ApplicationDegree
    at app4grad.college.ApplicationsController$$EPuFyMDe.index(ApplicationsController.groovy:14)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [app4grad.Application] to required type [domain.package.Application] for property 'application'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [app4grad.Application] to required type [domain.package.Application] for property 'application': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [app4grad.Application] to required type [domain.package.Application] for property 'application': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Try using an import instead; add `import domain.package.Application` and change `domain.package.Application` to `Application` inside the class

Comment: @BurtBeckwith sorry yes I had tried that already but when the `import` didn't work I had tried a direct typecast.  Neither of them work.  I had removed it not only because it didn't work, but also because my Intellij IDE said it was an unused import.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem is that you're using a reserved name :  https://grails.org/wiki/Reserved%20Names
Using Intelij Idea you can easily rename you're domain class and the IDE will do the rest for you.